# What kind of web server app do I need?

Tags: ios, gps, webserver

I would like to create a sort of tracking application.

A device with GPS will send it's location coordinates to a web server.

The client app on the iOS device will connect to the web server and will continuously the read the coordinates from the web server (that are being updated by the GPS device every 5 - or so - seconds)

Using GoogleMaps SDK I will put a marker on the map where the coordinates are, and refresh the location of the marker when the read value has changed.

My question is:
What kind of web technology would be suitable for receiving data (such as coordinates) and constantly updating this data as well as allowing the clients to continuously read this value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further research I discovered that gearheadalex's answer on this page was correct. I successfully created a node.js server using socket.io and was able to connect the iOS clients to the server and read GPS coordinates sent to the server from another iPhone. I then simply updated the MKPointAnnotation with the coordinates received from the server. (Of course this was done with apple maps, but I assume it would work the same with Google Map's GMSMarker)

I also have an alternate server that functioned the same using Python and Twisted for the evented system.

Answer (score 0):

I was part of a team that made nearly this exact application using a Node.js + Socket.io backend.
I won't speculate as to whether it is the best, but Node's evented system worked extremely well for this.